# Magento 2.3.5 : Path "/theme/origin" cannot be used with directory "/var/www/html/m235/pub/media"

Tags: magento2, theme

I am upgrading **Magento 2.3.3** store to **Magento 2.3.5**

I go to Themes tab in admin (**Content > Design > Themes**) and try to save my theme.

But it returns this error

> Path "/theme/origin" cannot be used with directory "/var/www/html/m235/pub/media"

How to solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For solution,

- Go to **theme** table from your database.
- Check your theme's **type** column value. It maybe 1 or 2.
- Change that value with 0 (Your theme's type column value).
- Now, Deploy store and clean cache and check it.

Comment: Thanks ! It's working.

Comment: Why Change that value with 0  ?

Comment: Need to set custom theme as physical type theme so.